# ninja: error: '../arm64-v8a/libknox_remotedesktopclient.so', needed by '.../arm64-v8a/libremote-desktop-sample-jni.so', missing

Tags: android

I have a working Android Studio project. However after I commit it to SVN and try to checkout the project, I get the following error:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /home/usr/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /home/usr/AndroidStudioProjects/test/ReactNativeApp/android/samsung_screenshot/.cxx/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a --target remote-desktop-sample-jni}

ninja: error: '../../../../libs/remotecontrol/lib/arm64-v8a/libknox_remotedesktopclient.so', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/libremote-desktop-sample-jni.so', missing and no known rule to make it
```